# Felix - how to correctly re-register service on bundle update?

Tags: java, osgi, bundle, apache-felix

I have some app, what calls some jar library, what calls Felix framework and added some bundles from bundles dir.

[image: project scheme]

The code of the "Show Help" button:

```
private void jMenuItem2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           

        for (Bundle qqq : context.getBundles()) {
            if ("ihtika2.I_AboutForm".equals(qqq.getSymbolicName())) {
                System.out.println("I_AboutForm state: "+qqq.getState());
            }
        }

        try {
            ServiceReference[] refs = context.getServiceReferences(
                    AboutFormInterface.class.getName(), "(Funct=*)");
            if (refs == null) {
                System.out.println("Not Found AboutForm on show");
            } else {
                AboutFormInterface AboutForm = (AboutFormInterface) context.getService(refs[0]);
                AboutForm.showWindow(context);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Ini.logger.fatal("Error on showing AboutForm", ex);
        }

    }  

In first click (before update) service founded correctly.

The code of the "Update" button:

  try {
            ServiceReference[] refs = context.getServiceReferences(
                    UpdaterInt.class.getName(), "(Funct=*)");
            if (refs == null) {
                System.out.println("Not Found UpdaterInt on demand");
            } else {
                UpdaterInt UpdaterLocal = (UpdaterInt) context.getService(refs[0]);
                UpdaterLocal.update();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Ini.logger.fatal("Error on showing AboutForm", ex);
        }
```

The code of the Updater's bundle:

```
public void update() {

        System.out.println("Stage 1");

        int x = 0;


        Map<String, Bundle> bundlesList = new HashMap<String, Bundle>();

        for (Bundle singleBundle : context.getBundles()) {
            bundlesList.put(singleBundle.getLocation(), singleBundle);
            System.out.println(singleBundle.getLocation());
        }

        System.out.println("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");

        Map<String, Bundle> treeMap = new TreeMap<String, Bundle>(bundlesList);
        for (String str : treeMap.keySet()) {
            Bundle singleBundle = treeMap.get(str);
            System.out.println(str + " " + singleBundle.getSymbolicName());
            if (!"khartn.Updater".equals(singleBundle.getSymbolicName())
                    && !"org.apache.felix.framework".equals(singleBundle.getSymbolicName())) {
                try {
                    System.out.println("state0 " + singleBundle.getState());
                    singleBundle.stop();
                    System.out.println("state1 " + singleBundle.getState());
                    singleBundle.update();
                    System.out.println("state1.1 " + singleBundle.getState());
                    singleBundle.start();

                    synchronized (this) {
                        try {
                            this.wait(250);
                        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println("state2 " + singleBundle.getState());
                } catch (BundleException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("***");
            }
        }


    }
```

On update main JFrame updates correctly - it hided and shown.
But on second click on "Show Help" Felix can't found service of the "Show Help".
"Show Help" service registration code:

```
package ihtika2.i_aboutform;

import ihtika2.i_aboutform.service.AboutForm;
import ihtika2.i_aboutform.service.AboutFormInterface;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;
import org.osgi.framework.ServiceRegistration;

public class Activator implements BundleActivator {

    @Override
    public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
        Hashtable<String, String> props = new Hashtable<String, String>();
        props.put("Funct", "AboutForm");
        System.out.println("Registering I_AboutForm");
         context.registerService(AboutFormInterface.class.getName(), new AboutForm(), props);

    }

    @Override
    public void stop(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
    }
}
```

The string "Registering I_AboutForm" on update showed.

Why Felix can't found re-registered service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is the adding to the Updater's bundle code call to the

```
context.getBundle(0).adapt(FrameworkWiring.class).refreshBundles(bundles, null);
```

as this described in [OSGi API Documentation](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/Bundle.html#update%28java.io.InputStream%29):

> If this bundle has exported any packages that are imported by another
>   bundle, these packages must remain exported until the
>   `FrameworkWiring.refreshBundles` method has been has been called or the
>   framework is relaunched.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why service is not found is that the interface `AboutFormInterface` is still wired to the previous revision of the updated bundle.

One of the solutions is to have interface defined in a third Bundle so it is stable during update.